# Disruptive 10k+ user in chat

Tags: support, chat, abuse

Would it be possible to disable the ability to see the flags of a specific user? This particular user counter-flags every flag that gets raised. He/she also thinks that it is appropriate to go afterwards to the channel where the flag originated and rant about it.

This behavior is harmful to the quality of chat content, since it prevents legitimate flags from being raised/handled.

Answer (score 16):

If a user is being disruptive, you can also raise a flag for moderator attention (those are different from the spam/offensive flags). That flag will only be visible to diamond moderators who can evaluate the situation and take appropriate actions.

Comment: +1 - Using the moderator flag is a good way to get attention to users who are abusive. Just to clarify, the moderator attention flag is in message actions. Click the down arrow on one of the user's messages, and then select "flag for moderator" at the bottom of the popout menu. This is different than clicking the flag icon or "flag as spam/offensive".